# Snowflake error in RStudio which limits the size of rows to fetch - Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695: HY000

Tags: sql, r, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an issue where I kind of know what it is but do not know the solution to it.

When I fetch data from an external Snowflake DB, it limits the size of the data that I can fetch in one query. For instance, I want to fetch data of of size larger than 1 million rows.

But the limit seems to be set to 1883 rows to fetch. I can fetch all rows when using the Snowflake browser and download it to .csv but not via RStudio. If I do not set the limit in the query to 1883 (max limit for some reason) then I cant fetch the data.

How do I bypass the size limit?

Query:

```
select (cast(mod_date as date)+(type-1)) as Date
, item_nr as Itemnr
, quantity as Forecast
, store_nr as Store
from MASKED.DB
where country = 'MASKED'
and store_nr in (MASKED, MASKED)
and mod_date > '2022-04-25'
and type < 4
order by Date
limit 1883;
```

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695: HY000: [Snowflake][Snowflake] (25) 
      Result download worker error: Worker error: [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://MASKED.blob.core.windows.net/results
      /MASKED%2Fmain%2Fdata_0_0_0?sv=2020-08-04&spr=https&se=2022-04-25T19%3A32%3A22Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=MASKED&rsce=gzip 
      failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=7 msg='Couldn't connect to server' osCode=10013 osMsg='Unknown error'.
    
     
Warning message:
In dbClearResult(rs) : Result already cleared
```

Comment: There no such limit in ODBC at least. The large result sets are usually retrieved directly from the Azure blob storage (internal stage called in Snowflake) and you actually might have a proxy in between that filters the internal stage. At least the error is suggesting that to me. Running [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) should confirm that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a solution to it?

Comment: You can whitelist Snowflake URLs returned by [SYSTEM$WHITELIST()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html) at proxy level or bypass the proxy via [env variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#using-environment-variables)

Comment: Thanks but you are just referring to Snowflakes documentation which does not help.

Comment: How can I refer then to something from your network when I don't really know how it looks like? Can you confirm at least if you have a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to set a proxy rule for Snowflake without manipulating environment variables.

**In any proxy program or in your solution set the rule like this:**

```
Applications: Any (any app/program can use it)
Target hosts: *.your_link_name.snowflakecomputing.com
Target ports: Any 
Action: Direct (not via HTTPS or SOCKET)
```